# How to recreate Lightroom clarity in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-lightroom

Adobe Lightroom have a awesome **clarity** slider which is missing from Photoshop. How one can recreate the same effect in PS?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Adobe CC or newer than Clarity can be found in Adobe Camera Raw filter towards the top of the filter menu, which gives you a version of Adobe Camera Raw that works even on jpgs. I suggest converting to Smart Object first.

If you're not on Adobe CC than you need to look at sharpening method tutorials because there's far too many to give you a run down of on here.